# Retrieving if all objects in a list have the same value for an attribute in python

Tags: python, list

I'm wondering how to quickly see if all objects in a list have an attribute set to a certain value, and if so run a portion of code. So far, in any program that I've written that needs this, I've done something similar to the code below.

```
listOfObjects = []
class thing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.myAttribute = "banana"
        listOfObjects.append(self)
def checkStuff():
    doSomething = True
    for i in listOfObjects:
        if i.myAttribute != "banana":
            doSomething = False
    if doSomething: print("All bananas, sir!")
```

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
if listOfObjects.myAttribute == "banana":
    print("All bananas, sir!")
```

Comment: Usually you would include a `break` after `doSomething = False` so you don't have to needlessly check the rest of the items. btw `all()` has this short circuiting behavior by default

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a generator expression in the `all` function.

```
def checkStuff():
    doSomething = all(i.myAttribute == 'banana' for i in listOfObjects)
    if doSomething: print("All bananas, sir!")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I would just you a generator expression (and [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)):

```
all(getattr(item, "myAttribute", False) == "banana" for item in listOfObjects)
```

*This has the potential benefit of not raising if item doesn't have a myAttribute attribute.*

---

Note: My original answer checked that all items had the attribute "banana" with [hasattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr):

```
all(hasattr(item, "banana") for item in listOfObjects)
```

Comment: This will check to see if the object has an attribute *named* banana, not that a specific attribute has the *value* banana.

Comment: @kindall updated to use getattr rather than hasattr.